# OpenCart DB query issue (syntax misunderstand)

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

OpenCart v1.5.3.1, Export plugin:

```
    $query  = "SELECT pd.*, cg.name FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_discount` pd ";
    $query .= "LEFT JOIN `".DB_PREFIX."customer_group` cg ON cg.customer_group_id=pd.customer_group_id ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY pd.product_id, cg.name";
```

Can anybody explain, what `pd` and `cg` means here?

Meet similar sintax in other places, but not sure what it means and how to work with it...

Looks like it is some common thing, but I am quite new to work with data bases yet, please help :-(

This query generate error:

> Notice: Error: Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list'            Error No:
>   1054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd is the alias name for table `product_discount`
cg is the alias name for table `customer_group`
```

---

```
Notice: Error: Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list' Error No: 1054
```

This would actually mean there is no field of name in the table `customer_group`

Comment: Thank you very much! Does `product_discount pd` means to use `pd` as such sinonim later in code?

Comment: It is defined right after the table name after the FROM in the query `product_discount pd`  || `customer_group cg`

Comment: Yes. that means you could reference the other fields later using `pd.fieldname1` instead of `product_discount.fieldname1`.